Keycloak : best way to manage per session role selection
I’m currently trying to find a way to manage per session role selection for our users.
We have multiple projects on the same apps and storage (jupyterhub and S3) and users are
supposed to be working on a single project to be compliant of our local laws, as they can’t match data from different projects.
I’ve been trying to find a solution to let the user post authentication select a single role that would be configured for a single project. I’ve been exploring the idea of creating a custom authenticator but this is way out of scope (and definitely out of my budget) to build one.
The only solution I can think of is creating one user account per project but some of our users have 10 projects which is definitely hard to manage.
Does anyone can think of a better solution ?
